# jQuery event callback and global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, callback, scope

I am facing a strange behaviour that defies my understanding of closures and scope in JS.

Here is my code sample :

```
  var cta_container   = $("#call_to_action_container");
  var cta_div         = "<div>SOME VARYING HTML</div>";
  var ruler           = $('<div id="height_ruler"/>');
  var ctac_height;


  ruler.append(cta_div);
  cta_container.append(ruler);
  ctac_height = ruler.outerHeight();


  // If we already reached phase 3, we don't attach handlers again
  if (!this.reached_phase_3) {
    cta_upper.click(function(event) {
      console.log("Height during click callback : "+ ctac_height);
    });
  }
  this.reached_phase_3 = true;


  console.log("Height before click : "+ ctac_height);
  cta_upper.click();// Manually triggering the click
  console.log("Height after click : "+ ctac_height);
```

This is part of a Backbone's View's method. 
Basically, I have a `div` I can toggle by clicking  on it. This `div` changes size over time. I access its `outerHeight` as a global variable from the `click` event callback. But the value within the callback scope doesn't get updated, although the value within Backbone's View's method gets updated properly.

For instance, on first click, this code might output :

```
Height before click :            100
Height during click callback :   100
Height after click :             100
```

And then, after the `div` height has changed, I click again and get for instance :

```
Height before click :            147
Height during click callback :   100
Height after click :             147
```

The value of the `ctat_height` variable gets updated within the method call setting up the callback, but not within the callback scope.

From what I know about closures, they don't copy global variables value within their scope, but access them via the scope chain. So how come `ctat_height` doesn't get updated properly?

I am quite sure I can easily find a workaround to this issue, but this wouldn't help me understanding why this is not working.

If someone could explain to me why it acts like this, or point me to an appropriate resource, I would be very thankful!

Comment: My guess is the click handler was bound during a different run through of this code, and as such, it's closed around the variable within a different scope than the one the other two console.logs are using. The need for `if (!this.reached_phase_3) {` is what prompts that guess. You should instead somehow remove the click events in teardown and re-add them.

Comment: I think I understand. You mean that every time I call the method (the enclosing function), I create a new scope. Thus if I call my method twice, I create scope n°1 and scope n°2. My variable does get updated properly within scope n°2, but my callback is tied to scope n°1 where values didn't change. 

Is this right?

Comment: Sounds obvious now. I believe a closure is the right solution then, so the outer scope of the callback won't be created again and again on each method call. 

Many thanks Kevin. That's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Kevin-b's answer, I found a very quick solution, which is to set the `ctac_height` variable within the View's scope (`this.ctac_height` instead of `var ctac_height`).